# set the time of countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a timer that works for two minutes. Initially it display time as

```
2:00
```

when i click on start, the time starts decreasing.It is working fine, but i want 2 things that i am not able to achieve

1) After the timer is finished i.e reached to 0:00 it should move back to initial value of 2:00
2)i want to ensure that this time should sync exactly with the server time.

here is my code.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#startClock").click(function () {
        $("#startClock").fadeOut().delay(120000).fadeIn();
        $("#submitamt").fadeIn().delay(120000).fadeOut();
        $("#walkaway").fadeIn().delay(120000).fadeOut();
    });
});
</script>



  <span id="count">2:00</span> 
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="startClock" value="Submit">Start</button>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submitamt" value="Submit">Submit</button>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" id="walkaway" value="Submit" style="display:none" >Walk Away</button>
```

can anyone please tell me how to do so

Comment: Can describe 2) _"this time should sync exactly with the server time"_ ?

Comment: show your html. what are submitamt and walkaway? Where is the timer in your page in html?

Comment: @Lelio Faieta edited my post

Comment: @guest271314 i wish to sync the time and independent of user's system time so that it cannot get affected if the user changes the time of the system

Answer (score 4):

Can you try this

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#startClock").click(function () {
            setInterval(function () {
            $("#startClock").fadeOut().delay(120000).fadeIn();
            $("#submitamt").fadeIn().delay(120000).fadeOut();
            $("#walkaway").fadeIn().delay(120000).fadeOut();

            },120000);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var count = $("#count");
  var interval = 0;
  var t = void 0;
  var d = new Date(1434094898542 + 22000).toString().slice(20, -15);
  count.text(d);
  $.fx.interval = 0;
  $("#startClock").click(function() {
    count.animate({
      color: 1
    }, {
      easing: "linear",
      duration: 120000,
      start: function(now, fx) {
        t = (1434094898542 + 22000);
        interval = setInterval(function() {
          t = t - 1000;
          count.text(new Date(t).toString().slice(20, -15))
        }, 1000)
      },
      complete: function() {
        clearInterval(interval);
        count.text(d)
      }
    })
    $("#startClock").fadeOut().delay(120000).fadeIn();
    $("#submitamt").fadeIn().delay(120000).fadeOut();
    $("#walkaway").fadeIn().delay(120000).fadeOut();
  });
  
});
```

```css
#submitamt, #walkaway {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre></pre>
<span id="count">2:00</span> 
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="startClock" value="Submit">Start</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="submitamt" value="Submit">Submit</button>
<button type="submit" name="submit" id="walkaway" value="Submit" style="display:none">Walk Away</button>
```

Comment: will it sync with server also?

Comment: @sammy Can dNot certain interpret  _"sync with server"_ correctly ? Can describe details ?

Comment: I want that a user can use this timer only once a day, so if the timer is not synced with server he can change his system date/time and use this timer more than once in a day, so i want to avoid it thats why wish to sync the timer with server time

Comment: @sammy _"a user can use this timer only once a day"_ Still not certain about application ? `startClock` clicked one time within "once a day" , animation begins, ends ; clicked second time no animation occurs ? Is expected result for `click` event to run at most once per day per user ?

Comment: @sammy Note, _"a user can use this timer only once a day"_ not appear at Question ?

Comment: @guest271314 nice code, but can you tell me how can we recode if we want just the time i.e 2:00 without GMT+0530 (India

Comment: @st001 Not certain what _"want just the time i.e 2:00 without GMT+0530 (India"_ means ? Where does _"GMT+0530 (India"_ appear at `html` , `js` ?

Answer (score 1):

This function will do for you for what your first question:

```
   function countdown() {
        seconds = document.getElementById('count').innerHTML;
        seconds = parseInt(seconds, 10); 
        //this is to show a message on the last second of the timer            
        if (seconds == 1) {
            temp = document.getElementById('count');
            temp.innerHTML = "Last second!!!";
            return;
        }
        seconds--;
        temp = document.getElementById('count');
        temp.innerHTML = seconds;
        timeoutMyOswego = setTimeout(count, 1000);
    }

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#startClock").click(function () {
       countdown(); 
       setTimeout(function(){        
            $("#startClock").fadeOut().delay(120000).fadeIn();
            $("#submitamt").fadeIn().delay(120000).fadeOut();
            $("#walkaway").fadeIn().delay(120000).fadeOut();
            $('#count').html('2:00');
        },120000);
    });
});
```